# K fold In python

Tags: python

I have problem when using fold with python only one index of one fold shown in y_test ? my data contain 4240 records and only 424 shown in `y_test` and `x_test`?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
kf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10,n_repeats=10, random_state=9)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):
    print("TRAIN:",train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Comment: Isn't this the expected behavior? `n_splits=10` means each fold, and so each test set, should have 1/10 of the data.

Comment: yep, should be like this, what is the problem?

Comment: Ok but in the end I should have 4240 records in x , y training and testing.          In my case I have result of only on fold